# Is it worth creating an identical mapping class just to avoid the dependencies?

Tags: mongodb, oop, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

Document database like MongoDb lets you use your business objects directly by attributes attributes to fields/properties as shown below.

```
public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Here [BsonId] attribute specifies a MongoDb primary key. Even though it can be though as a flexibility, it is very specific to MongoDb. Now the Book class is becoming depending on MongoDb libraries as well. As different projects (projects in .net, packages in Java etc.) use the above Book class, they also become dependent on MongoDb libraries and that in turn breaks the loose coupling between projects.

Given the background, is it worth creating an identical mapping class just to avoid the dependencies (or use tools like Automapper https://automapper.org or http://dozer.sourceforge.net/ for Java)?

Is it worth the extra plumbing vs violating the principles of loose coupling of sub-systems and single responsibility principle?

Comment: Using a [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object#Example), like `BookId`, for the book id would eliminate the dependency of the `Book` class to a specific underlying persistence layer.

Answer (score 0):

`Book` class is dependent on MongoDb at compile time. However since you have used only attributes from MongoDb, `Book` is not dependent on MongoDb at run time.

That means when the object code for Book is loaded in CLR, and if the MongoDb dll is not found, then you will not get `TypeLoadException`. In C# (also in Java) when the dll where the attribute is defined is not found while loading, there is no exception. The attribute dll will be loaded optionally when found.

So this means you can use book in a environment when MonogoDb can not be loaded. You can distribute the dll containing book without the dependency of MongoDb. The dependency is only at compile time, and this dependency is definitely taken care of if you code compiles.

Now to have a identical class without attribute would be too much of work for nearly nothing.